# Find $(A \cup B)$ given conditional probability

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm being asked to find $P(A \cup B)$ given

$$P(A) = 0.15,\ P(B) = 0.45, \ P(B\mid A) = 0.20$$

I know the equation for conditional probability is

$$P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$

Although I'm not sure how to use this to solve the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wish to calculate
$$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$
Given $P(B|A)$ and $P(A)$, can you find what $P(A\cap B)$ is?

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling it would simply be that but I wasn't quite sure.

Answer (score 1):

$$P(A \cap B) = P(B|A)*P(A) = 0.03$$
$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) = 0.57$$

Answer (score 1):

$P({B}|{A})=0.20 \implies \dfrac{P({B}\cap{A})}{P({A})}=0.20 \implies \dfrac{P({B}\cap{A})}{0.15}=0.20 \implies P({B}\cap{A})=0.03$

---

$P({A}\cup{B})=P(A)+P(B)-P({A}\cap{B})=0.15+0.45-0.03=0.57$