# Finding probability of $A\cup B$ given probabilities of $A$ and $B\mid A$

Tags: probability, proof-verification

> Find $\mathbb P(A\cup B)$ given that $\mathbb P(A)=\frac15$ and $\mathbb P(B\mid A)=\frac7{20}$.

[Here's a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1308126/find-a-cup-b-given-conditional-probability), but I don't have the advantage of knowing $\mathbb P(B)$. Is it needed to find the solution to this exercise?

I know that

$$\mathbb P(A\cup B)=\mathbb P(A)+\mathbb P(B)-\mathbb P(A\cap B)$$

and

$$\mathbb P(A\cap B)=\mathbb P(B\mid A)\cdot\mathbb P(A)=\frac7{100}$$

However, I'm not sure how to compute $\mathbb P(B)$. I can show that

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(B)&=\mathbb P(B\cap A)+\mathbb P(B\cap A^C)\\[1ex]
&=\frac7{100}+\mathbb P(B\mid A^C)\cdot\mathbb P(A^C)\\[1ex]
&=\frac7{100}+\mathbb P(A^C\mid B)\cdot\mathbb P(B)\\[1ex]
&=\frac7{100}+(1-\mathbb P(A\mid B))\cdot\mathbb P(B)\\[1ex]
\implies\mathbb P(B)&=\frac7{100}\cdot\mathbb P(A\mid B)
\end{align*}$$

but then I have the problem of finding this new conditional probability. I can't think of any other manipulations that don't lead in circles.

Is the question missing essential information to find the desired probability?

Comment: @Henry I'm not sure I follow. Did you mean $\cap$ in place of $\cup$? I don't see how that's true unless $A\cup B=A\cap B$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not determined.

Scenario $I$:  you draw uniformly from $\{1,\cdots, 100\}$.  $A$ is the event "the draw is $≤20$."  $B$ is the event "the draw is $≤7$".  Then $P(A\cup B)=P(A)=\frac 15$.

Scenario $II$:  you draw uniformly from $\{1,\cdots, 100\}$.  $A$ is the event "the draw is $≤20$".  $B$ is the event "the draw is $≤7$ or $=21$".  Then $P(A\cup B)=\frac {21}{100}$.

Comment: Thanks for illustrating the point with an example!

Comment: No problem.  As you can see, there is nothing special about the numbers involved.